# Best way to recreate Partitions on a hard disk using previous output of "fdisk -l" on Linux

Tags: disk-management

Say you have the output of `fdisk -l` for your drive, which has Start,End,Blocks,Id,System

What's the best(ie=easiest/quickest yet accurate) way to recreate the partitions from that?

Simply running `fdisk /dev/sdX` will ask for sectors or size of partition not "Blocks".

Ideally a way to convert the `fdisk -l` file. I have to `sfdisk -d` output format would be nice since then I could easily just do a `sfdisk /dev/sdX < fdisk-l_convertedto_sfdisk-d.txt`

Answer (score 1):

It seems I may have stumbled on what the problem was. It seems my `fdisk -l` output was from old version of fdisk which used "cylinders" as the output. Starting fdisk with: `fdisk -c=dos -u=cylinders /dev/sdX` seems to "finally allow" me to use start/end values from my `fdisk -l` output. Also I discovered the "Blocks" in fdisk output is actually "kb" so its easy to calculate size of the partition.

Hope it helps others, if you can't figure out why Start/End values aren't accepted or don't match you may simply need to start your newer fdisk with compatibility mode set to `dos` and `-u` set to `cylinders`.